# Is There A Way To Delete Files As They Are Being Extracted With 7-zip?

Tags: zip, storage

Currently I'm sitting at a nice 62gb of free space with a zipped folder taking up 44gb, My current problem is that it needs to be extracted and I just barely don't have enough free space to do so. I've done all the cleaning and optimizations I could to my storage so the next obvious solution would be to delete the files as they are being extracted but I don't exactly know how I would go about doing that with 7-zip. I've already done a little searching on this problem to see what I could do and will continue to do so but I thought it would be smart to ask and see if someone might have a solution already to a similar problem

Comment: @RicardoBohner Probably should've clarified, I'm trying to delete the zipped folders files after extracting them from inside, not deleting the files I extract

Comment: If you delete most of the extracted files why not simply extract only the needed files?

Comment: I'm not deleting any of the extracted files, I'm deleting the zipped folder after I extract everything from it

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a stretch, but according to the [7-zip forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/e0b79f5b/), you could temporarily change the temp folder to an external drive, although the message thread suggests that it won't work.

A bit more research shows that the program doesn't use a temp folder if you are specifying a destination folder. Drag and drop apparently does use a temp folder.

An easier way to approach this might be to use a high capacity flash drive to hold the zip file and extract it to your destination. A sufficiently high capacity drive (128 GB) may allow you to contain both the zip file and allow you to extract it to the flash drive.